# Tableau Web Data Connector giving error

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to use tableau web data connector to fetch all data from our custom api and show in a dashboard. But I am getting the following error.

`The version of Tableau that you are using cannot use the web data connector that you are trying to access. The connector requires at least version '2.1.1' of the web data connector API.`

Currently, I am using Tableau 10.0.1. Here is the screenshot. [image]
I appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the connector you are trying to access (earthquakeMultitable) is trying to use a version of the WDC API with which your Tableau Desktop version is not compatible.

In this case, you are using the WDC 2.1 API, and Tableau Desktop 10.0.  Tableau 10.0 can only use versions 1.1 and 2.0.  There is a lookup table here:  http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_library_versions

In order to fix this error, you can either:

1. Upgrade to Tableau 10.1.
2. Have your WDC use the latest WDC 2.0 API instead: https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-2.0.latest.js. In the earthquakeMultitable.html file, you will find an include script that includes https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-2.1.1.js, so you will just want to update that line to point to 2.0.latest.js.

The default version you will find on Github is always the latest version of the SDK (in this case, it's currently the 2.1 SDK).  If you'd like to get the 2.0 SDK, you can find it here: https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector/releases/tag/v2.0.1

Comment: Thank You, As you said I upgraded to Tableau 10.1.1 and everything is working fine.